# Java Crash while downloading File

Tags: java

I want do download a big .jar file from my own Server. (https://luis.team)
There for I made a thread to download it, because it is very huge.
Here is my code for download:

```
public Update(String version, File outputFile) {

    URL url;
    URLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Luuuuuis/InstantVerify/master/version");
        connection = url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    assert connection != null;
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
        String[] versionCode = in.readLine().split("&&");

        if (!(versionCode[0].equalsIgnoreCase(version))) {

            /*
             * Download from URL given in version file
             */

            if(versionCode[1] != null && !versionCode[1].equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {

                Thread th = new Thread(() -> {

                    try {

                        URL downloadURL = new URL(versionCode[1]);

                        URLConnection urlConnection = downloadURL.openConnection();
                        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");

                        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                        int length;
                        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }

                        inputStream.close();
                        outputStream.close();

                        InstantVerify.version += " (outdated)";


                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                th.start();

            }
        } else {
            InstantVerify.version += " (latest)";
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

After this I get a very little file(around 30MB) and an Java Runtime Error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f8fd9b5ed10, pid=14021, tid=0x00007f8fa5b56700

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_201-b09) (build 1.8.0_201- 
b09)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.201-b09 mixed mode linux- 
amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [libzip.so+0x11d10]  newEntry.isra.4+0x60

Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core 
dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

An error report file with more information is saved as:
/home/ServerTest/Bungee/hs_err_pid14021.log
Compiled method (nm)    6767  201     n 0       
java.util.zip.ZipFile::getEntry (native)
total in heap  [0x00007f8fc517a510,0x00007f8fc517a868] = 856
relocation     [0x00007f8fc517a638,0x00007f8fc517a678] = 64
main code      [0x00007f8fc517a680,0x00007f8fc517a868] = 488

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
Aborted
```

I guess there is a issue with Memory Mapping in Java, because my root Server has only 2GB of RAM.
What can I do do fix this? Thank you.

Comment: An error report file with more information is saved as:
/home/ServerTest/Bungee/hs_err_pid14021.log -- this file is also interesting because it shows more stack traces, which might give you a better idea about what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue with a workaround.

```java
URL downloadURL = new URL(versionCode[1]);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) downloadURL.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
Files.copy(inputStream, outputFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
inputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

A SIGBUS error is a misaligned data error which is being thrown by the Operating System. Which basically means that the data is not aligned correctly for the platform your server is running on. As an example some unix systems insist that all data is aligned on 8 byte boundaries. It looks like the file has been successfully downloaded and that it is a call to java.util.zip.ZipFile::getEntry that is causing the crash. If you enable core dumping on that platform the java developers should be able to determine if the bug is in the building of the initial zip file or in the reading of the zip file.

Comment: Ok thanks. I found out a couple of people had the same issue, too. It seems to be a known Java bug. And I found a workaround for my project.